# Debugging Rails application with Textmate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, ruby-debug

How do you guys debug your Rails apps?  I have seen a link to datanoise.com that is supposed to show how to use ruby-debug with Textmate using a bundle.. but it looks like the page is down.  Does anyone know how to set this up?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@johnmcaliley - I debug my rails apps by simply adding 'debugger' to my code:

```
method_call
variable = method_call + 5
debugger
#more code
```

Then start your rails web server with the --debugger option:

```
script/server --debugger
```

This requires you have a gem installed, ruby-debug, I think.  Check out this screencast for a good demo: http://railscasts.com/episodes/54-debugging-with-ruby-debug

However, it doesn't hook into textmate.

Comment: Robert, thanks for the reply.  This was an option I was looking at and the screencast you provided helped me understand how it works.  But I am still looking for something that will hook in to Textmate.  I am working with Rails 3 beta and Ruby 1.9.2.  I had to install "ruby-debug19" for Ruby 1.9 compatibility.  I also installed RubyAMP bundle and it provides mechanisms to set breakpoints in Textmate and run the debugger from a terminal.  Still trying to hack it to get Rails 3/Ruby 1.9 to work.

Comment: @johnmcaliley, I did some searching and came up with this which might interest you (it did me....I've been contemplating trying out this mythical text-mate).  Apparently there is a ruby or rails debugging bundle for textmate that allows you to hook the other way. 

Check out http://objectmix.com/ruby/758472-ruby-debug-textmate.html http://blog.macromates.com/2008/textmate-ruby-tricks/ and http://macdevelopertips.com/textmate/textmate-execute-inline-ruby.html

Comment: Thanks for the links Robert.  That is what I was looking for.  I will let you know how well it works with Rails 3/ Ruby 1.9.

Comment: BTW, you should really try out Textmate.  You will be amazed at the power of bundles and its speed.  My productivity increased noticeably after I switched to TM.  The lack of a built-in debuggger is my only gripe with the IDE.